# Why is JSON deserialisation with System.Text.Json so slow?

Tags: c#, json, go, .net-core, system.text.json

I have the same minimal project that deserializes a json 100,000 times written in C# and in Go. The performance varies greatly. While it is nice to know that performance goals can be achieved by using Go, I would much prefer to achieve comparable results in C#. Given that C# is 193x slower, I assume the mistake is on my side, but I cannot figure out why.

#### Performance

```
$ dotnet run .
real    1m37.555s
user    1m39.552s
sys     0m0.729s

$ ./jsonperf
real    0m0.478s
user    0m0.500s
sys     0m0.011s
```

#### Source code C#

```
using System;

namespace jsonperf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{\"e\":\"trade\",\"E\":1633046399882,\"s\":\"BTCBUSD\",\"t\":243216662,\"p\":\"43818.22000000\",\"q\":\"0.00452000\",\"b\":3422298876,\"a\":3422298789,\"T\":1633046399882,\"m\":false,\"M\":true}";

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                if (0 == i % 1000)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Completed: {i}");
                }

                var obj = BinanceTradeUpdate.FromJson(json);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace jsonperf
{
    public class BinanceTradeUpdate
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("e")]
        public string EventType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("E")]
        public long EventUnixTimestamp
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public DateTime EventTime
        {
            get
            {
                return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(EventUnixTimestamp);
            }
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("s")]
        public string MarketSymbol
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("t")]
        public long TradeId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("p")]
        public double Price
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("q")]

        public double Quantity
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("b")]
        public long BuyerOrderId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("a")]
        public long SellerOrderId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("T")]
        public long TradeUnixTimestamp
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public DateTime TradeTime
        {
            get
            {
                return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(TradeUnixTimestamp);
            }
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("m")]
        public bool BuyerIsMarketMaker
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonPropertyName("M")]
        public bool UndocumentedFlag
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static BinanceTradeUpdate FromJson(string json)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BinanceTradeUpdate>(
                json,
                new JsonSerializerOptions()
                {
                    NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString
                });
        }
    }
}
```

#### Source code Go

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/csv"
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "strconv"
)

type Float64Str float64

func (f *Float64Str) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
  var s string

  // Try to unmarshal string first
  if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &s); err == nil {

    value, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)

    if err != nil {
      return err
    }

    *f = Float64Str(value)
    return nil
  }

  // If unsuccessful, unmarshal as float64
  return json.Unmarshal(b, (*float64)(f))
}

// Trade represents an exchange of assets in a given market
type Trade struct {
  EventType     string     json:"e"
  EventTime     int64      json:"E"
  MarketSymbol  string     json:"s"
  TradeID       int64      json:"t"
  Price         Float64Str json:"p"
  Quantity      Float64Str json:"q"
  BuyerOrderID  int64      json:"b"
  SellerOrderID int64      json:"a"
  TradeTime     int64      json:"T"
  IsBuyerMaker  bool       json:"m"
  Flag          bool       json:"M"
}

func main() {

  jsonString := "{\"e\":\"trade\",\"E\":1633046399882,\"s\":\"BTCBUSD\",\"t\":243216662,\"p\":\"43818.22000000\",\"q\":\"0.00452000\",\"b\":3422298876,\"a\":3422298789,\"T\":1633046399882,\"m\":false,\"M\":true}"

  // open stdout
  var stdwrite = csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)

  // convert string several times into obj
  var trade = Trade{}
  counter := 0

  for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &trade); err != nil {
      stdwrite.Flush()
      panic(err)
    } else {
      counter++

      if counter%1000 == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%d elements read\n", counter)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to benchmarking properly, then you need to use a Benchmarking tool.  This will provide a fairer result.   Also, you need to remove all Console writes, these are VERY slow and will skew your results.   You also have some inefficiencies in your C# code such as creating a new JsonSerializerOptions for every interation, when this should be a single global setting.

Comment: while all-in-all what you are saying is not wrong, please note that dotnet requires far longer than 90s to complete the task. printing 100 lines to the console and ie VM initialisation are rounding errors here. I tested earlier by wrapping .FromJson() in calls to System.Disgnostic.Stopwatch .Start() and .Stop(). It makes less than 2 seconds difference.

Comment: Well if I run your code then it takes me ~83 seconds.  If I use a JsonSerializerOptions initialised just once then it takes 232ms.  Removing the Writeline saves another ~30ms which is a > 12% performance increase (over the 232ms).

Comment: Chapeau, I would never have considered that the initialisation of JsonSerializerOptions is that expensive of ab operation. That helps me a lot; thx a lot.

Comment: A quick look at the source, suggests that metadata for each type is cached in the `JsonSerializerOptions`. A static cache would be faster for your use case, but that would prevent type information from being garbage collected. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerOptions.cs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason this takes so long is that you’re initialising a new `JsonSerializerOptions` object everytime.

Initialise the serialiser once & you’ll see huge performance improvements (70%+ for me).